# Displaying Image in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display an Image from Database. But, I am getting the following error.

> The best overloaded method match for System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(string) has some invalid arguments.

Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Category ID
        </td>

        <td>
            Category Name
        </td>

        <td>
            Category Image
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.CategoryID</td>
        <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
        <td><img src="@Url.Content(item.CategoryImage)" /></td>

    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: what value you are getting in : `item.CategoryImage` ?

Comment: what data type is `item.CategoryImage`? It would have to be a string to the path of the image and I think you are passing it bytes, in which case `@Url.Content` is not the right choice.

Comment: I am just getting this error. The best overloaded method match for System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(string) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes. passing it bytes. Using byte[] as datatype for image field

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(System.String)

Comment: Why do you store images in your database? Why do you want to display the images as embedded, do you realize this is going to blow up your page size and reduce responsiveness? Why don't you introduce a component (handler, controller) that returns the decoded images as ... images?

Comment: At my company, I have two very large systems that I developed. They both use resources that I store in the database, otherwise it's such a huge pain in the butt to replace them and you tend to waste space by having them stored in two places. There are plenty of reasons to store the binary images in a database, hence the reason why every single database has some sort of Binary or Image value type.

Comment: @Kevin I am not here to start the "resources in database versus resources on filesystem" discussion. I'm asking very relevant question to the OP to determine the direction of the desired solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I gotcha. Merely just wanted to point out that in certain situations it's not a bad way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code that I use :

```
    private static string ImageByteToBase64ImageTag(byte[] array)
    {
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(array);
        return "<img class=\"img-responsive center-block\" src=\"data:image/png;base64," + base64 + " \"  />";
    }
```

In this case, it would be much easier to work with the image as a base64 image. My code is pretty straight forward but all you have to do is pass an array of the image and get a base64 string. You can even return the image via JSON if you format it right. You can return just the following portion in a ViewBag or Model:

```
ViewBag.ImageData = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String
```

And in your html

```
  <img src="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ImageData)" />
```

Or in your model, just make a string property for the image.

Comment: As discussed in comments under the question: this is _an_ approach, but may not be the most viable. It depends on many factors, among others the number and size of images. If we're talking 1 MB of images and 1 KB of HTML, then your page will suddenly be more than 1,3 MB of HTML (because of the inline, base-64 encoded images) and the browser will not start rendering before all HTML is downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult GetImage()
{
   var imageFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("ImagePathHere");
   var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      srcImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
      return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
   }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "share your favorite snippet" site. This action method assumes a file to exist on disk, while in this question it resides in a database column. A code-only answer also isn't a good answer, try adding some explanation of what the code does next time.

Comment: If you inspect the code before you talk, you can see this File method gets byte[] and returns FileContentResult and you can understand what I mean.

Comment: If you explain what the code does before dumping it, I won't have to read it line by line to try and understand what you're trying to say. That being said I stand by my previous comment: the code you posted expects a file to exist, which isn't the case here.

Comment: And also, this code converts any image format to PNG, which is very resource exhaustive.

Comment: There are 5 rows in my codes so you won't spend to much time on these I think, If you read them line by line. You can change the format of the image. And Yes my code expects a file but the guy who asked this question keeps the data as a byte[] ! But I wish I wrote some explanations because I replied to you more.